# How to test my offline content based app is working fine after restoring the backup from Apple iCloud?

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I have created a offline content based app[new app not available in app store yet] and i am storing all the contents inside cache folder as per iOS Data storage guidelines. None of content will be backed up during iCloud backup for any user. In a ideal scenario If the user does a restore of his device using iCloud backup, my app will installed from app store automatically after successful restore operation.But now my app will not have any contents already downloaded and was used by user so i need to download everything again.

The problem is how to simulate this scenario because after i do restore from iCloud my device tries to connect to app store and install the app. Since this is a new app and i haven't posted it in app store yet so app doesn't get installed after restore operation and i couldn't test my app after iCloud backup.

Is there a better way to simulate testing scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to restore then install your app manually (from iTunes)? I think iOS restore uses a "safe place" for app restored data and keep it there for some time until the app is effectively installed.